# Redux action's as function or as constants what the difference

Tags: reactjs, redux, redux-actions

I learn Redux and wonder about this two ways of creating action(Action Creators)

NR:1

```
export function itemsIsLoading(bool) {
    return {
        type: 'ITEMS_IS_LOADING',
        isLoading: bool
    };
}
```

NR2

```
const saveUserFailure = errMsg => ({
    type: 'SAVE_USER_FAILURE',
    payload: errMsg,
});
```

I read that Redux Thunk need the `function` version but I also see example where the `const` version is used?

Is the NR1 version for Thunk reducers?
and the NR2 for Redux basic reducer?
Is the NR1  version an "Action Creators" or are both that?

What's the difference?

Comment: A thunk is an action creator that returns a function. Your "normal" action creators return an object that should always have a `type` property and usually a payload. If you don't need to pass any arguments when creating an action you could define the action as an object, for example `const resetAction = {type:RESET}` if you define it as an action creator it would be: `const resetAction = ()=>({type:RESET})`

Comment: Do you mean a "normal" action creators is the "`const saveUserFailure..`" that I show in my question? So "action creator" is always the function-return-a-function ?

Comment: An action creator is a function that returns an action. If the function returns a function then the action is a thunk action and if it returns an object then it's a "normal" action creator.

Comment: In these two examples there is essentially no difference.  It’s just a different syntax for writing the same thing.  Both are action creators.  Both are functions (the const version is often referred to as an “arrow function”).  You can read up on arrow functions [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/Arrow_functions) if you are interested in learning more about the minor behind-the-scenes differences, but for your purpose they are equivalent and interchangeable.